# Как добавлять класс css динамически?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть меню, все элементы которого открываются вправо вниз лесенкой.
Кроме последнего, последний элемент должен открываться вправо вверх.
я добавил:

```
.menu ul li:hover > .bottom-menu{
  bottom: 0; 
  top: auto; 
}
```

Но нужно делать это динамически. Т.е. у меня все категории меню перебираются итератором `each` (+ например, у последнего элемента 4 уровня вложенности и класс `.bottom-menu` нужно добавить всем субменюшкам.)

**Какие есть варианты для таких случаев?**

```css
html,*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 16px;
}

body{
background: #eee;
}
a{
text-decoration: none;
}
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li{
  display: block;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  position: relative; /*это добавить*/
}
.menu ul li a{
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu ul li.active > a,
.menu ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}


.menu ul li .submenu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.menu ul li:hover > .submenu{
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li:hover > .bottom-menu{
  bottom: 0; 
  top: auto; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
            <ul class="submenu submenu2">
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
                <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
                </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!--// Inner Child 2 -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul><!--// Inner Child 1 -->
      </li>

      <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
            <ul class="submenu submenu2">
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
                <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
                </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!--// Inner Child 2 -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul><!--// Inner Child 1 -->
      </li>

      <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
            <ul class="submenu submenu2">
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
                <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
                </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!--// Inner Child 2 -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul><!--// Inner Child 1 -->
      </li>

      <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
            <ul class="submenu submenu2">
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
                <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
                </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!--// Inner Child 2 -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul><!--// Inner Child 1 -->
      </li>
      <!-- вложить сюда во все submenu -->
      <li class="active "><a href="">Sample</a>
        <ul class="submenu bottom-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li class="active "><a href="">Sub</a>
            <ul class="submenu submenu2">
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
                <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
                </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!--// Inner Child 2 -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul><!--// Inner Child 1 -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--// end .menu -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уточните, каким именно элементам вам требуется добавить класс `.bottom-menu`? Всем `.submenu`, вложенным в последний элемент первого уровня? Или всем `.submenu`, вложенным в последний элемент каждого списка?

Comment: Нужно добавить к `<ul class="submenu submenu1">`, т.е. добавить во все submenu последней меню.

Comment: я добавил комментарий в код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить класс `.bottom-menu` ко всем `.submenu`, вложенным в последний элемент списка меню, можно вот так:

```
$('.menu ul > li:last-child .submenu').addClass('bottom-menu');
```

Либо вы можете использовать этот селектор без введения нового класса:

```
.menu ul > li:last-child .submenu {
  bottom: 0; 
  top: auto; 
}
```